# Angularjs - cross controller Factory Update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers which shares same factory. One of the controller is updating factory variable. Other should watch for that change and display later.

This is how I tried:
http://plnkr.co/edit/q1NS6ytRduLlbcgJlnDU?p=preview

But it does not work. What is the best and correct way to share variables across controllers? How to make my code work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem has noting to do with AngularJS but rather with closure behavior in JavaScript for primitive values. In short if you've got a closure over a primitive type it is a copied value that is accessible in your local function. You are loosing connection to the original variable and can't modify it from the local scope.

Change the primitive value to an object reference and your code will start to work as expected: http://plnkr.co/edit/gEQ2KPsEEtBRfTbjqPcO?p=preview

Comment: So, is the factory in that example a singleton? I thought only services are singletons.

Comment: @finishingmove Factories and services are singletons.

Comment: @finishingmove .factory, .service and .provide are just different way of describing how to create instance of objects (usually called services in AngularJS terminology). All those objects are singletons. Unfortunately the "service" word is a bit overloaded so it is easy to get confused.